# How to count the maximal number of letters in a string?

Tags: c

How to count the number of (A I E O) letters in a string? I have tried to make it work but it doesn't for whatever reason. First i tried to add some more libraries and still it didn't work then i tried to add some more variables and work with cycle for,still no effect. I have this code which should do it but it just closes after execution.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <conio.h>


int main()
{
    char str[100];
    char pick[4]={'A','E','I','O'};
    int i,j=0,kol,sor;


    printf("Write: ");
    scanf("%s",str);



   kol = INT_MIN; 
   for(i=0;i<strlen(str);i++){
        if(str[i]==' '){
            j++;
           }
   }
   printf ("%d",j);
   int  words[j],max[j],min[j];
   words[0] = 0;
   for(i=0;i<strlen(str);i++){
    if(str[i]!=' '){
            for(int g=0;g<4;g++){
                if(str[i]==pick[g]){
                    words[j]+=1;    
                }
            }
        }else{
                max[j]=i;
                j++;
                min[j]=i+2;
                words[j]=0;
            }
   }
   for(i=0;i<j;i++){
        if(kol<words[i]){
            kol=words[i];
            sor = i;
           }
   }
   for(i=min[sor];i<=max[sor];i++){
        printf("%c",str[i]);
   }


    return 0;
}
```

Maybe the code is wrong,maybe something more should be added?

Comment: "It didn't work" -- Could you be a bit more specific, please? What's you input? What results do you get and what results did you expect? Or does "it didn't work" mean that you couldn't compile the program or that it crashed?

Comment: It just closes after executing.

Comment: Initializing your arrays might help.

Comment: If you run the program from some IDE it closes because it is done. If you want to avoid this, run it from a shell or wait for some user input at the end.

Comment: We love that you're here and we can't reproduce your problem without knowing the input you use.

Comment: Maybe you mean that the input is the string introduced from keyboard.

Comment: Can you add what is your input and what is you expect output?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show us an example of input and expected output. For example: _My input is: `ABIOX` and I expect the program to output this: `???`_, ??? being the output you expect.

Comment: The input is something like AAA III OO EEEEEE and the output should be   A = 3 I = 3 O = 2 E = 6.  But as i said it works fine for input but it closes afterit.

Comment: I exected the code with the sample input which you provide, The output I received was 0. You say it works fine for your input, Did you receive output as 0 or any other value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char str[100];
    int a = 0, e = 0, i = 0, o = 0;
    printf("Write: ");
    fgets(str, sizeof(str), stdin);

    for(int c = 0; str[c]!= '\0'; c++)
    {
        switch(str[c])
        {
            case 'A':
            case 'a':
                a+=1;
                break;
            case 'E':
            case 'e':
                e+=1;
                break;
            case 'I':
            case 'i':
                i+=1;
                break;
            case 'O':
            case 'o':
                o+=1;
                break;
        }
    }

    printf("A = %d E = %d I = %d O = %d",a,e,i,o);
    return 0;
}
```

Given input is stored in "str". For loop is used to get individual characters from the string. Then it was checked with switch cases and the number of items is counted.

***Note***: You could remove switch cases with smaller case "a,e,i,o" if you need to count only Upper case characters.

Comment: @Tohluka., If this answer resolved your issue, please consider marking it as accepted. It will encourage us to write more answers.